# in the South vs of the South

Tags: prepositions

> There is one state that is in the South, but not of it.

I have met this sentence in a book explaining about prepositions.

Despite the explaining, I cannot catch up how the meaning is different between In the South and Of the South.

In my supposition, the state in the context does not belong to the South completely, because the state is not of it.

Comment: Please try to link to sources, in this case it is Seth Lindstrom's "English Prepositions explained" https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=V4ylHBrzTQsC&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=%22There+is+one+state+that+is+in+the+South,+but+not+of+it.%22&source=bl&ots=H5sJVuRAoj&sig=XMi-iIMq3fptuA38CCeFG6B15TI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK_s-166LXAhUMcBoKHd9sCUIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22There%20is%20one%20state%20that%20is%20in%20the%20South%2C%20but%20not%20of%20it.%22&f=false

Comment: The author is almost certainly using a parallel to the advice that [Christians should be in the world, but not of the world](https://412teens.org/qna/what-does-in-the-world-not-of-the-world-mean.php).

Answer (score 6):

> in the South

This would refer to actual geographic location

> of the South

This would likely refer to association/origination. Thus, the full sentence means the state is southern by location, but culturally or socially it doesn't appear to be southern.

Answer (score 3):

It means Florida may be **in** the south in terms of  geography (for instance,  where it is found on a map)  but it's not part **of** the traditional South as a cultural region.